# Tracking hand rotation with RotatedRect

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV for a project to detect hand gestures, I managed to isolate the hand and drawing the convexes the hand is appearing very clearly now. My goal is to detect if the hand is rotating or moving left or right.

I used RotatedRect to figure out if the hand is rotated or not, but it seems like the RotatedRect is always tilted left or right (mostly left) even if my hand is straight. How can I possibly fix that?

[image: Image of hand]

Here's my code for creating and drawing the RotatedRect:

```
double angle;
            RotatedRect rc = minAreaRect(biggestcontours[hand]);
            if (rc.size.width < rc.size.height) {
                angle = 90 - rc.angle;
            }
            else {
                angle = -rc.angle;
            }
        Point2f rect_points[4];
            rc.points(rect_points);
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                line(onehand, rect_points[j], rect_points[(j + 1) % 4], Scalar(255, 0, 0));
            }
```

**Remark**:biggestcontours[hand] contains the contour of  my hand.

Comment: Draw a line from mid point finger to the below then analyze the movement of that line to decide right or left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach using  PCA

[You can find the code here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/dee/tutorial_introduction_to_pca.html)

Result:

[image]

Note: if the hand shape doesn't change and you have a reference angle, you'll be able to get it's rotation angle accurately.